# Select a Generic Grouping (not static) of Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a current Excel Macro below which works great for *one* dataset:

```
Sub test_macro()
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
        Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("B1:K1")
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End Sub
```

The goal is to take a dataset that looks like this:
[image]

And transform it to this:

```
| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|-------|
| Foo1 | Foo2 | Foo3 | Foo4 | Foo5 | Foo6 | Foo7 | Foo8 | Foo9 | Foo10 |
```

And this works great as is. However, the number of columns I have can change. Sometimes it is only 2 columns, sometimes it is up to 250 columns. Therefore, I am worried about the `Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("B1:K1")` portion of my macro, since it specifies the paste range to be `B1:K1`.

Therefore, How can I make that destination range generic? (I am simply shifting over row 1 by 1 to the right for every filled in cell in row 1).

Comment: Implying that I haven't done research is not a constructive criticism to better my question or help others. Also, I know of no other method other than select to grab the appropriate row values (to ultimately shift), so I don't know how to set a `range`. I am not sure how that helps.

Comment: I didn’t flag it for closure mate and nor did I down vote it, that was someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked. I had to specify ranges.

```
' This sub opens the workbook
Sub Open_WB()
' Turn off screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
' Open data
Workbooks.Open "dummy_wip.xlsx"
' Activate data
Dim databook As Workbook
Set databook = Application.Workbooks("dummy_wip.xlsx")

MsgBox ("Got here")

' Format the data per Michelle Barstad Requirements
  Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
        Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    ' Dynamically look for resizing
    Dim seltocut As Range
    Dim seltopaste As Range
    Dim cellstart As Range
    Dim cellfinish As Range

    Set cellstart = Cells(1, 1)
    Set cellfinish = Cells(1, 2)
    Set seltocut = Range(cellstart, cellstart.End(xlToRight))

    Range("B1").Select
    Set seltopaste = Range(cellfinish, cellfinish.End(xlToRight).Offset(, 1))

    seltocut.Cut Destination:=seltopaste
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a read on how to avoid using `.Select`... Otherwise I`m not sure if the number of the ",," commas can vary between your columns (in which case a better replace management needed), but as a working example based on your sample, the below should work on any number of columns/rows. See comments in code for some more details:

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub splitColumns()

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

Dim databook As Workbook
Set databook = Application.Open("dummy_wip.xlsx") 'Can allocate directly to the variable on .Open

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = databook.Worksheets("SheetName") 'Best to declare the worksheet objects too
Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'get the last row
Dim arrSplit() As String, strToSplit As String
Dim R As Long

With ws
    For R = 2 To lRow   'loop through all values
        strToSplit = Replace(.Cells(R, 1), ",,", ",") 'Replace 2 commas with 1... if you might have more than 2 at once, you will need a better replace
        If Left(strToSplit, 1) = "," Then strToSplit = Right(strToSplit, Len(strToSplit) - 1) 'Get rid of leading comma if any

        arrSplit = Split(strToSplit, ",") 'split the values at comma
        .Range(.Cells(R, 2), .Cells(R, UBound(arrSplit) + 2)) = arrSplit    'Allocate the values back to the spreadsheet in column B
    Next R
End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With

End Sub
```